# current project's namespace "does not exist" error in Razor editor only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

Since upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 last week, I am having the familiar "The type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace 'Y' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" error. It happens only in the Razor editor in Visual Studio 2019, and refers to the *current project's* namespace. I have tried all the familiar solutions found on several other StackOverflow questions, including cleaning and rebuilding, clearing all the caches, deleting the .suo file and other VS-generated files, uninstalling plugins, changing the target framework (and changing it back), ensuring the namespace is referenced in the Views/web.config, and removing references to libraries that target old versions of the .NET Framework. This is a very common error message, but as far as I can tell, none of the other questions discussing this error talk about Visual Studio reporting that it is unable to find the namespace of the current project.

[image: example Razor View]
[image: the model class]

The screenshots show an example. The red squiggly line under `Web` in `Tasks.Web.Models` shows the error in detecting the class that is shown in the second screenshot. The project is named Tasks.Web. The default namespace is the same, and every class file within the project has a namespace that begins with `Tasks.Web`.

The project is an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that was created in 2015, and has been happily upgraded in VS2015 and VS2017 up till now without ever seeing this issue. The project still builds and runs; the only real downside is that Intellisense keeps showing me this error and it appears in the Error List at least once for every view file I have open. It's easy enough for me to keep working with this issue, or go back to VS2017, but I'd rather solve it, and possibly understand why it's happening, if it's not simply a bug. This seems to happen on every Razor view referencing a model class defined in this project, whether I use the full path in the `@model` statement or try to use a `@using` statement instead. Any ideas?

**Addendum**: Changing the namespace to `WebHack` via a R# Rename refactor has the following effects:
1. Successfully changes the namespace in all `*.cs` files and `*.cshtml` files (showing that the refactor is able to detect that the namespaces are the same).
2. No change in tool behavior. The red squiggly is still there, showing the same error for the updated namespace. **NOTE**: removed R# after doing this test, with no change.

**Addendum 2**: Updated to Visual Studio 2019, Update 3 (16.0.3). No change. Pulled a clean copy of the source code into a new directory, ran "Load Dependencies" in Visual Studio, built solution. No change; shows the same "does not exist" error squiggly on "Web" in this new copy of the solution, too.

**Addendum 3**: Isolated to Visual Studio by actually uninstalling all extensions. Removed references to Resharper in the question text.

Comment: Found a related issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/476877/type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-3.html)

Comment: It seemed worth a try, even though that issue refers to a namespace provided by a different project (in my case, the "reference" to another project isn't relevant, since the views are in the same project as the supposedly missing namespace). I went in and upper-cased all the project GUIDs in my "web" project (some were upper and some were lower, probably dating back to VS2015) and it had no effect.

Comment: Have you tried with `Tools > Text Editor > C#  > Advance > Full Solution Analysis`? One more thing, if you are not using latest version of `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` try updating or re-installing it.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it a couple hours ago, with and without the "use external process" experimental option that comes underneath it. Didn't see any changes.

Comment: And what about `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`? Visual Studio intellisense heavily depends on package `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`. Updating the package will hopefully resolve the issue.

Comment: It's looking like that's going to do it. Is that behavior is different from VS2017 to VS2019? In any case, I updated that package and we're in business. Want to put that answer in an Answer?

Comment: Sure. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the Nuget package `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` will resolve the issue. Now `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` is more dependent on `Roslyn`. Seems like they have added more to it than the previous versions that cause the intellisense to behave inappropriately on Visual Studio 2019.